# FIrebase Realtime Database Reference.addValueEventListener is not working when I call at the first time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get children counts and set it as my key, so that the database would be read easily.

It would look like this.

[image]

When I click the button to insert a new data to database,  `reference2.child(Rname).addValueEventListener` method is not work.

The childpath(ordercnt[0]) in `reference2.child(Rname).child(ordercnt[0]).child(Integer.toString(i)).setValue(order);` is null and cause crashed.

```
Cart_submitBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.Cart_submitBtn);
       Cart_submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {                
               String Rname = selected.get(0).getRName();

               reference2.child(Rname).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                       if(snapshot.exists()){
                           ordercnt[0] = Long.toString(snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                       }
                       else{ ordercnt[0] = "0"; }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                   }
               });                
               reference1.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                       User user = task.getResult().getValue(User.class);
                       if(user != null){                            
                           for(int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
                               String order = "";
                               
                               order += "餐點名稱: " + selected.get(i).getsName() + " ";
                               order += selected.get(i).getsCnt() + "份";
                               order += selected.get(i).getsPrice() + "元 ";                              
                               reference2.child(Rname).child(ordercnt[0]).child(Integer.toString(i)).setValue(order);
                           }                                                        
                       }
                   }
               });
           }
       });
```

Error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `reference2.child(Rname).child(ordercnt[0]).child(Integer.toString(i)).setValue(order);`, run in the debugger, and check which of the values in the line is `null`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think ordercnt[0] is null. I have tried to code that `if(ordercnt[0] == null){ordercnt[0] = "0"}` before I setvalue. And then it can run successfully. But everytime I rerun the app, the data which I insert first will be replace. It means that reference.child(Rename).addvalueEvent is not work. However, besides the first insert, other insert will get children counts and set the right value as their key.

Comment: What I mean about the first data be replaced is that data of key is 0 will be change as the first insert value I rerun app.

Comment: If you try to log the value of `ordercnt[0]` inside the first onDataChange, are you getting the correct value? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `null` because you do for `reference1` outside the method `onDataChange` from `reference2`.

Put your `reference1` below the `else{ ordercnt[0] = "0"; }`

```
           reference2.child(Rname).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                   if(snapshot.exists()){
                       ordercnt[0] = Long.toString(snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                   }
                   else{ ordercnt[0] = "0"; }
                   //Put your reference1 at here
                   reference1....

               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

               }
           });
```

Comment: Thank you. You remind me that I can chage the codes order. I put `reference2.child(Rname).addValueEventListener` outside the onclick method. When I click the button, it only call  ` reference1.child().addOnCompleteListener`  method. The get childrenCount will be called when I start the activity and data get change will also get called once.